# WP Customizer API loaded into functions.php

Tags: functions, theme-development, theme-customizer, api

Heyo,

I'm once again sort of stuck with my Customizer API. I've worked quiet a lot on the Theme Customization of my Theme and my functions.php is getting a bit out of hand. Is there a way I can put all these "panels/sections/settings/controls" in an extra file and just load that file into the functions.php?

And even thoe is there a way I can load that file only if the Customizer is open?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can load the code in the `customize_register` action. One example:

```
<?php
// File: functions.php
add_action( 'customize_register', function( $wp_customize ) {
    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/inc/customize.php';
    wpse256532_customize_register( $wp_customize );
} );
```

And the `inc/customize.php` file:

```
<?php
// File: customize.php
function wpse256532_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->add_setting( /* ... */ );
    $wp_customize->add_control( /* ... */ );
    // ...
}
// ... any additional customizer classes and other includes ...
```

Comment: This somehow doesn't work for me ... The website loads but if I go into the customizer, it looks like an php error. If I change the 'customize_register' into 'some_customize_register' the customizer loads but doesn't have the custom panels/sections.

Comment: You're right. I neglected to pass along the `$wp_customize` argument from the `customize_register` action. I just updated the example to include this.

Comment: This once again didn't work for me. Am I doing something wrong? I change the 'wpse256532_customize_register' to 'mytheme_customize_register' in both files and change the '/inc/customize.php' into '/inc/mytheme-customize.php'. Its the same thing ... I get a white site (php error) and if I change the 'customize_register' into 'mytheme_customize_register' it loads the customizer but not my custom Pannels/Settings.

Comment: Changing `customize_register` to `mytheme_customize_register` will just prevent the logic from being called at all, since `mytheme_customize_register` is not a valid action. There's a chance that you're on an older version of PHP that doesn't recognize `__DIR__` so I changed the example to use `dirname( __FILE__ )` instead.

Comment: I've now used this method on a new theme and it works like a charm ... no idea what was wrong with the earlier theme I created back than ... thank you!